# Scan special string using sscanf

Tags: php, scanf

I want for example to scan this `$lang['foo1']='foo2';` from a PHP file so I tried
this but it doesn't work.

```
$file = "../lang/lang.en.php"; 

if(file_exists($file)) {
    $text = fopen($file, 'r+');
    $content = trim(file_get_contents($file, NULL, NULL, 221)); 
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $n = sscanf($content, "\$lang['%s']=%s;", $s1[$i], $s2[$i]);
        echo $s1[$i].'==>'.$s2[$i];
        $i++;
    } while($s1[$i]! = '' && $s2[$i] != '');
}
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should just `include('../lang/lang.en.php')` like a normal PHP file.

Also, it's possible to make `lang.en.php` return an array directly with `return`, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: i want to get this `$s2[0]=foo2; ` and `$s1[0]='foo1'`

Comment: When you want to exactly `$s2[0]` with an integer you have to remove the `'` in your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-match-all.php) in your case.

```
// Match 
// $lang['PAGE_TITLE']='Meine Webseite Titel';

$content = file_get_contents('../lang/lang.en.php');
preg_match_all("~\$lang\['.+'\]\s=\s'.+';~", $content, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Don't Work my File For language ==>`$lang['PAGE_TITLE']='Meine Webseite Titel';
$lang['HEADER_TITLE']='Meine Website-Header Titel';
$lang['SITE_NAME']='Meine Website';
$lang['SLOGAN']='Mein Slogan hier';
$lang['HEADING']='Position';

// Menu

$lang['MENU_HOME']='ACCUEIL';`  You Understand my idea is to require every value step by step like array('MENU_HOME'=>'ACCUEIL'...) ;

Comment: I changed the regular expression a little bit, since I see your content. Btw... german?